# Simple math formula to calculate average

Tags: java, php, c, math, data-structures

I am making a software that deals with employee trust. I am trying to make a math formula (no need to tell that I am bad in math :) ).

Here is the scenario:

```
Employee 1 trusts employee 2 = > 20% or 0.2 (average trust of employee 1 with employee 2)
Employee 2 deals with 10 customers => 13%  (average - 10 customers trust on Employee 2)
Employee 1 also deals with 7 customers that customers belongs to Employee 2's 10 customers. => 37% ( average 7 customers trust on employee 1)

Employee 1 dealt with 10 customers for last 17 years.
Employee 2 dealt with 7 customers for last 1 years.
```

Now I want to calculate that how can we say that Employee 1 is much trust worthy than Employee 2? If I just see average than I can say Employee 1 but he only dealt with customers for 1 year. Now I want to make a generic formula to see which one is more trust worthy and I want to use all three values that are ( employee to employee, employee to customer, and number of year) to calculate average percentage. I want to increase or decrease an employee trust based on these values. Please remember I want to decrease as well for some employee I can not say that all employee or 90+ employee are trust worthy etc.

What I did:
I just simply plus employee to employee and employee to customer trust weight

```
Employee 1 = 0.57
Employee 2 = 0.33
```

I don't know what to do for years.

Current system just calculate employee to employee trust that is not good enough to trust itself.

I am not restricted to any programming language because I just want to make a generic formula. All ideas and suggestions are most welcome !

If you think my problem relates to any previously developed trust model then please do let me know (I already know web trust model but I don't know how to fit that in my situation)

Comment: Might be worth loking at Google's PageRank algorithm? It's a related concept and could give you some inspiration....

Comment: Shouldn't this be on math.stackexchange.com? Maybe it's just over my head because I don't understand how you arrived at your example percentages.

Comment: As some background info, formally this is called Bayesian Probability, or the Bayesian Model of Probability, which takes into account the classical probability and "degree of belief". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a logarithmic function for this.

```
y = k*log(t+b)
```

`t` is the time they've maintained their customer relations in some useful unit of time (years, months, etc.), `k` and `b` are constant factors determined experimentally. Add or multiply the result of this equation to what you have so far.

Comment: pardon me, I couldn't understand about K and B :(. I just have three values in the current system (database).

Comment: They're not *in* your database. They're constant factors that you determine experimentally. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method

Comment: It was a long long article still I couldn't find if they mentioned about these factors or how can I get them? any other hint?

Comment: Pick some values. Try them. See if they work. If they don't, then pick other values and try again. Keep going until you find values worth using.

Comment: @Tweety, the most obvious values for k and b are 1 and 0. This leaves you with a function log(t).  However, you may find this unsatisfactory and the general formula shows you how to adjust it to taste.

Comment: @Tweety, it might help you understand the purpose of k and b if you enter the formula into a graphing calculator so you can easily see the effects of altering their values. A free online graphing calc http://my.hrw.com/math06_07/nsmedia/tools/Graph_Calculator/graphCalc.html and then enter 1*log(x+0) into the y1 field, then click graph. up and down represents trust, left to right represents time. good luck

Comment: Would you add more light as to how you came up with this?

Comment: @David: You want time to count, but you don't want it to be a crushing advantage. The logarithmic function allows more time to give a higher score, but results in diminishing returns (e.g. the difference between 5 and 10 years is the same as the difference between 10 and 20 years).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think trust can be simply averaged - it's a serious area of research. Here's a typical paper:
http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~rckerr/KerrCohen-pst06.pdf
which uses considerably non-linear functions.

Comment: I do not calculate trust and it is not my problem as well :) that is HR department who use some performance and other parameter to manually calculate this and enter into the system. Thanks anyway